# How to define a model of episodes w a series as foreign key in django effectively

Tags: python, django

Hi and thanks for your time!

I have a model of series and a model of episodes (different apps) with a series as a ForeignKey for the episodes. I have a few issues:

1. Isn't a bit of a mess to have all episodes in the same model whithout taking into account the series they belong to (ofc there's the foreignkey, but they are all shuffled together)? If it is, how could I solve it?
2. With my current model, I don't know how to create a field that automatically adds the number of episode taking into account the episodes that already exist of a **CONCRETE SERIES**.
3. I have a DetailView of each series in my app "series" (url = `series/<slug(of the series)>/`, and I want to define a DetailView for each episode. Should I define the url in the episodes app or in the series app?
4. Once I have the url, how do I get the the episode object in the DetailView most effectively? I first thought of getting all episodes in the get_qs and then filtering in the context_data, but I don't know how to get the series out of the URL to filter, and this method seems quite long to me. How could I do it?

Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Isn't a bit of a mess to have all episodes in the same model whithout taking into account the series they belong to (ofc there's the foreignkey, but they are all shuffled together)? If it is, how could I solve it?

If the episodes are all of a kind and you have unique fields across them, like for example you require the primary key (or ID) or the slug to be unique for all of them, independent of their series, then it's good if they are all in one table.

If, on the other hand, you want to be able to delete a complete series' episodes and reset their PK to 1 (e.g. if you import them on a regular basis and don't want to increment the PKs like crazy) or if you might have a bit different models per series, you might want to use a simple abstract model. You could share code but they would reside in different DB tables. (You could also have a look at GenericForeignKeys, but that might be over the top.)

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

> 2. With my current model, I don't know how to create a field that automatically adds the number of episode taking into account the episodes that already exist of a CONCRETE SERIES.

You could override `save()` in your model (or the abstract base class) and simply increment it, depending on how many episodes for this series you already have:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.episode_no:
        # if you are using a fkey without specific reverse name and
        # self.series is configured to not allow null/blank
        series_count = self.series.episode_set.count()
        self.episode_no = series_count + 1
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that `bulk_create` does not call `model.save()` - but in this case you should be setting the episode number for each object in the bulk beforehand, anyway. It's probably best not to automate too much in this case because you might not always add the episodes in their actual order?

> 3. I have a DetailView of each series in my app "series" (url = series//, and I want to define a DetailView for each episode. Should I define the url in the episodes app or in the series app?

Depends on what the URL of the episode should look like. Should it be at first level? More REST-like would be:

urls.py

```
url_pattern = [
    url(r'^series/$', SeriesListView.as_view(), name='series_list'),
    url(r'^series/(?P<slug>[\w_]+)/$', SeriesDetailView.as_view(), name='series_detail'),
    url(r'^series/(?P<series_slug>[\w_]+)/episodes/$', EpisodeListView.as_view(), name='episodes_list'),
    url(r'^series/(?P<series_slug>[\w_]+)/episodes/(?P<slug>[\w_]+)/$', EpisodeDetailView.as_view(), name='episodes_detail'),
]
```

With Django 2.0 you should be able to use `<slug:slug>` and `<slug:series_slug>`.

> 4. Once I have the url, how do I get the the episode object in the DetailView most effectively? I first thought of getting all episodes in the get_qs and then filtering in the context_data, but I don't know how to get the series out of the URL to filter, and this method seems quite long to me. How could I do it?

Use the generic [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview). The following snippet together with the linked documentation should get you going.

```
class EpisodeDetailView(DetailView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        series = get_object_or_404(SeriesModel, slug=self.kwargs.get('series_slug'))
        return super().get_queryset().filter(series=series)
```

Comment: Then you should accept the answer to let others know.